# i want to filter treenodes on the textbox text changed event in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

[Filter a Treeview with a Textbox in a C# winforms app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260322/filter-a-treeview-with-a-textbox-in-a-c-sharp-winforms-app)

i got this but how to make treeviewcache?

Comment: when i trying to ,make copy and filter the treeview on text changed,it  does not displays any records in treeview control

Answer (score 0):

Define :

`TreeView _fieldsTreeCache` in `Designer.cs` and then initialize it in FormConstructor:`this._fieldsTreeCache = new TreeView()`

Comment: but that will not copy the treeview nodes...that is just initialization.

Comment: I checked the comment in that thread.It says:populate it when ever you add or remove nodes. or somewhere else like Form_Shown.It is name of your trieview,you can populate it (by anymeans you are doing).You said you have trie view already .